# Getting java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to [B when trying to update a domain object

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

Using Grails, I have defined a domain class that looks like this:

```
class User implements Serializable {
    .
    .
    .
    int id
    byte [] password_Salt
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I retrieve an instance of this, the "password_Salt" property is populated correctly.

However, I want to update just that field, so I am using the following:

```
def valuesMap = [:]
valuesMap['salt'] = new byte [] { .... };
valuesMap['userId'] = ....
User.executeUpdate("update User set password_Salt=:salt where id=:userId", valuesMap)
```

but I get Grails runtime exception "java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to [B"

I'm sure there must be an obvious solution, but I've been looking at this for hours.

Thanks,

Carl

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just updating the value (user.salt = ...) and then calling user.save()?  Also your example syntax appears wrong as new byte [] { ...} is invalid.

Comment: Hello.  The problem with doing "user.save()" is that the database is a legacy system and doing that updates all the fields, not just the ones I have changed, which causes problems.  The "new byte" statement is wrong, I was just giving an idea of what I was doing.

Comment: If you're getting updates to fields you haven't changed, then there is more than one thing wrong.  However, there does appear to be a bug related to using byte arrays in executeUpdate statements.  You may wish to report this to grails-gorm or hibernate.  Until that is fixed, you may need to look into why you can't use gorm to update specific database fields; that did work with byte arrays in my testing.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll see if there is another way to skin this particular cat